# Can MooTools FX do acrobatic dance move?

Tags: mootools

I have an assignment of using MooTools's Fx to mimic the acrobatic moves of the [AngularTalk](https://sberan.github.io/angularTalk/).

I guess the html elements can be faded out and moved around, but unlike a linear move what exactly is manipulated and with what math function to make it acrobatic like? Any hint would be appreciated. Thanks.

[image]
<sub>(source: [strongspace.com](https://www.strongspace.com/saigon/public/admin/mootoolfx.jpg))</sub>

Comment: this is reveal.js - https://github.com/hakimel/reveal.js/ - CSS3 transitions based around classes. nothing to do with mootools or angular. mootools cannot natively do CSS3 transitions as it lacks the parsers for the props.

Comment: Oh! Thanks a big deal. Would you know if reveal.js comparable with MooTools?

Comment: reveal is nothing but a presentation framework for giving talks, based around HTML5. mootools is general purpose utility framework with classes. this is akin to comparing a road and a car. if you would like to recreate the effect using javascript, use velocity - a general purpose animation framework for modern browsers - https://github.com/julianshapiro/velocity - the 3-d flip/perspective effect is not something you will find in IE.